# How to give fadein effect to a div tag using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `Ul` tag on **hover** of it, I display a `div` using css.
Now i want that div tag will 1st fadein or any other effect like animate etc.
I know it can be done easily by using `jQuery`, but want to know can i achieve this using Html5,css3,css

[Here JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cedue/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fading in http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/Cedue/7/

There was never anything like `-webkit-opacity` or `-moz-opacity`

If you want to transition the `opacity`, then either write

```
transition: opacity 1s
```

or

```
transition: 1s
```

Comment: Your fiddle works, but doesn't address what was actually causing his issues (at least on my version of Chrome). You removed the "display: none;" and "display: block;" from .hdshw , which if you remove from his fiddle (e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/Cedue/18/ ) actually does allow the animation. Of course, your animation is prettier because you're correctly transitioning the opacity, and thus the text as well, whereas just removing the display lines on his causes the background to animate and the text to appear instantly.

Comment: I have tested on chrome,firfox and it works fine, but not int IE9 ?
If it possible to have same effect for IE browser

Comment: Not without using JavaScript. IE9 and older don't support transitions.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, removing the `display: none;` and `display: block;` lines from your code enables animation:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cedue/31/

(That is a copy of your original fiddle with only the display: lines removed.) However, this raises the issue that you can access, highlight, and even hover the text when it's hidden; if you do not wish to have that behavior you might wish to look into another means of hiding it until the correct area is hovered, such as shifting it with margins.

As Ana has mentioned, as well, if you wish to animate the entire fade you should use opacity as your transition parameter (e.g.: `transition: opacity 1s ease;`, with the additional lines for separate browser support). If you use background as the transition property as you do in your example, only the background fades and the text appears instantly.

EDIT: due to my own curiosity I tested this under Chrome and Firefox, each for both Windows and Mac, and can confirm that removing the `display` lines caused the animation to work on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [site](http://brugbart.com/Articles/javascript-fade), it uses css and javascript.

Pure CSS implementation [here](http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/).

Comment: thank you the link, i tried that but in my case have to apply effect on another tag, imean hover on ul which shows div tag with some effect

Comment: apply the fade class to the div that is getting created.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into CSS3 transitions http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understanding-css3-transitions/

Comment: thank you for reply, but here in my case have to apply effect on another tag

Comment: Your link to JsFiddle only shows the results for me, but not code. I can't see what exactly you're doing